# CMOS body voltage question

Tags: cmos, nmos, pmos

So I'm thinking in terms of the cross-section of this circuit, and I wanted to know how would I find the body voltage of M1 and M2 (which isn't shown on this diagram but I'm thinking in terms of the cross-section image)? Is there some expression that can be derived to get the body voltages? My textbook just assumes it's tied to the source to present this but I was wondering what if it wasn't?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If by body you mean the substrate of integrated circuits then I can tell you that it's never left floating.

Substrate is always connected to something.

No one takes the risk of leaving a part of the circuit unconnected, especially in CMOS technology.

---

When simulating the 3D behavior of electronic semiconductor devices, simulators calculate the voltage V(x,y,z) of all the device: source area, drain area, channel area, substrate, etc.

To answer your question:

The substrate voltage V is a function of x, y, z.

Comment: is there a way to derive an equation to get the voltage of them?

Comment: At college they never thought me one.

Comment: That isn't the case for silicon-on-sapphire integrated circuits, where the substrate is unconnected as it is an insulator.

Answer (score 1):

In typical circuits like CMOS inverter, the body voltage is a given parameter. You need not calculate this parameter because it is defined by the circuit network: technology, components and design. In discrete transistors the body is most often connected to the source, and the body voltage is equal to the source voltage. In digital integrated circuits, the body of NMOS transistors is connected to the ground and the body of PMOS transistors is connected to the highest voltage, VDD.

The designer of digital integrated circuits often has no choice as to the connection of body terminals: for example, n-well, in which PMOS transistors are fabricated, is a single well for many transistors, and the die substrate plays the role of the opposite well.

In more advanced designs, the body terminal can be used as a second gate or the designer can use body biasing in a **triple-well** technology. The threshold voltage depends on the body voltage: biasing the body voltage, you can increase or decrease the threshold voltage. The higher threshold voltage slows down and the lower threshold voltage speeds up the device operation. [The formula for the threshold voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#Body_effect) is
$$
V_{TB}=V_{T0}+\gamma \left({\sqrt {V_{\text{SB}}+2\varphi _{B}}}-{\sqrt {2\varphi _{B}}}\right)
$$
where \$V_{TB}\$ is the threshold voltage with biasing, \$V_{T0}\$ is the threshold voltage with zero biasing, i.e., when the body is connected to the source terminal, the other parameters are derived from the material properties of the device.

Answer (score 0):

In simple CMOS logic circuits there are default connections to the bodies of the MOSFETs. For NMOS transistors the body is connected to the lowest circuit voltage, which is usually ground. For PMOS transistors the body is connected to the highest circuit voltage, which is usually the power supply voltage. The reason for this is that the easiest and most area-efficient method of building the transistors uses the same physical structure (the wafer bulk, or an N-well, or a P-well) for the bodies of all transistors of a given type. The bodies of all NMOS transistors are connected together and the bodies of all PMOS transistors are connected together.

For an inverter, this effectively means that the transistor sources are connected to their bodies. But this is **not** true for gates with transistors in series, like NAND and NOR gates.

This is the conventional way of building logic gates. However, it is possible to connect other voltages to the transistor bodies to modify their operational characteristics, such as threshold voltage.